# Extending Survey Content Type

Tags: content-type, survey-list

Does anyone know of a limitation that would prevent a developer from creating a new Content using the Survey Content Type as a base?

We are hoping to add a few columns to that base Survey List.

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer your question directly but we extended the project task list via code and that worked very well. I think that it is the safest way when dealing with out-of-the-box lists.

Comment: Was that a 'Project Task' or 'Task' that you extended from?

Comment: Project Tasks lists on SharePoint 2010.