# How to extend the Survey content type?

Tags: content-type

This may be basic but being a novice in SharePoint, I am not able to figure out how to create a new Content Type with Survey as base type. Adding a new Content Type in Visual Studio presents me a list of type from which I can select but Survey type is not present there.

Please help me out.

Comment: Does this help: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17730/extending-survey-content-type ?

Comment: @eirikb I have already seen that. It doesn't help. I need guidance on how to do this exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't because the Survey Content Type don't exist

Surveys are lists with BaseType="4", which has it's fields defined in the `<BaseTypes>` section in SharePointRoot\Template\Global\XML\ONET.xml

As all list get a content type which inherits from the base content type of their items, this also happens for Surveys, but their local content type inherits from 0x System

Comment: You are right! I ended up creating my own list definition based on Survey and then customizing it.

Comment: @Mayank , Can u pls elaborate ur implementation?