# Is this possible to add new content type in survey list?

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-type, survey-list

I need to add a custom page in sharepoint survey page, So I would like to add it in the content type, by that I can add my custom page into survey list. Unfourtanetly I don't see any options to add custom content types to survey list.

I looked into

[How to extend the Survey content type?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46400/how-to-extend-the-survey-content-type)

I need more details about this, Please suggest me some idea to solve this issue.